# Express Jade dynamic header content using include

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm currently working on building a website on top of NodeJS with Express and Jade. All my content is pulled by an internal API which is handled by Express, this includes the navigation and page content.

I retrieve the page content and parse it to the view as an object:

```
app.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
   var pageId = req.params.id;
   sharepoint.listItems.list('Public Pages', function(err, items, nextUrl){
       for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
               if(items[i].Title == pageId){
                   res.render("pages/index.pug", {item: items[i]})
                   console.log(items[i])
               }
        }  
    });
})
```

In my Jade view i display the content and include a header:

```
include ../partials/header
block content
h2 !{item.AuthorId}

 div !{item.Content}
```

Now the problem is that I retrieve my header links in a different call on my express server:

```
app.get('/api/navigation', function (req, res) {
     sharepoint.listItems.list('Navigation', function(err, items,nextUrl){
         res.send(items)
     });
});
```

My question is what is the best way to include the object from the navigation call into my header.jade? As of now, i'm not parsing the navigation links into the header.jade file.

I like the idea of separating the  API calls, so I would rather avoid to call the navigation endpoint inside mu page call function.

I hope it makes sense.

Comment: You shouldn't be calling `res.render` inside your loop, it should only be called once. Pass your `items` collection instead of each individual item.

Comment: The `res.render` will only be called once because the pageId is unique.

Comment: if pageId unique still no sense of loop simple use {item: items[pageId], nav:nav}  now use nav variable in header

Comment: the nav variable is being generated in a different route (as explained in ot), so should I nest the calls? (Callback hell....)